# Perl XS and C++ passing pointer to buffer

Tags: perl, xs

I know almost no C++ so that's not helping, and my XS isn't much better.  I'm creating an XS interface for a C++ library and I have almost all my methods working except one.

The method in Perl should look like this:

```
$return_data = $obj->readPath( $path );
```

The method is defined as this the .h file:

```
int readPath(const char* path, char* &buffer, bool flag=true);
```

The "buffer" will get allocated if it's passed in NULL.

There's two additional versions of readPath with different signatures, but they are not the ones I want.  (And interestingly, when I try and compile it tells me the "candidates" are the two I don't want.)  Is that because it's not understanding the "char * &"?

Can someone help with the xsub I need to write?

I'm on Perl 5.14.2.

BTW -- I've also used a typemap "long long int" to T_IV.  I cannot find any documentation on how to correctly typemap long long.   Any suggestions how I should typemap long long?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never dealt with C++ from C or XS. If it was C, it would be:

```
void
readPath(SV* sv_path)
   PPCODE:
      {
         char*  path   = SvPVbyte_nolen(sv_path, len);
         char*  buffer = NULL;

         if (!readPath(path, &buffer, 0))
            XSRETURN_UNDEF;

         ST(0) = sv_2mortal(newSVpv(buffer, 0));
         free(buffer);

         XSRETURN(1);
      }
```

Hopefully, that works or you can adjust it to work.

---

I assumed:

- `readPath` returns true/false for success/failure.
- `buffer` isn't allocated on failure.
- The deallocator for `buffer` is `free`.

Comment: The part of your answer that solved this for me was understanding that I didn't need to use the C++ XS structure -- Class::method(...) -- in the xsub.  I kept trying to find a signature that XS would accept but once I did away with that it was much easier to solve.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Second part of the question is TYPEMAP for `long long` (or `long long int`).

Normally `long` is at least 32 bits and `long long` is at least 64. The default typemap for `long` is `T_IV`. Perl's equivalent for `long long` is `T_IV`, too.

But sometimes, you wan't to reduce warnings for cast. So, you can use `T_LONG` for `long`. `T_LONG` is an equivalent to `T_IV` but explicitly casts the return to type `long`. The TYPEMAP for `T_LONG` is descripted at $PERLLIB/ExtUtils/typemap

With this knowledge you can write you own TYPEMAP for `long long int`:

```
TYPEMAP: <<TYPEMAPS
long long int T_LONGLONG

INPUT
T_LONGLONG
  $var = (long long int)SvIV($arg)

OUTPUT
T_LONGLONG
  sv_setiv($arg, (IV)$var);
TYPEMAPS
```